# Search same values form different column

Tags: sql

I want to search for the same value in a different column, for example in the upload picture. We can see tel1, tel2 and tel3 have the same telephone number. how can I search it form script  [image]

I have one table only, I want to search a data from the table, example : our customer tel no is 65432100, I need to find this number appear in which order _id. In this case, 65432100 appear in order_id 1,3,5

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What is the exepected outcome and the real question? Since this query is very simple (at least if your description provides the whole requirement), you should tell us if you tried to find the query on your own and what exactly wrent wrong.

Comment: You can use a JOIN operation like `Select t1.* from t t1 inner join t t2 on t1.tel = t2.tel2`. But you need to describe you intention more clearly.

Comment: I have one table only, I want to search a data from the table, example : our customer tel no is 65432100, I need to find this number appear in which order _id. In this case, 65432100 appear in order_id 1,3,5

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an `IN` clause.

```
SELECT order_id, cust_name, tel1, tel2, tel3 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE 65432100 IN (tel1,tel2,tel3)
```

If the columns are of type varchar, write '65432100' instead of 65432100.

As long as you want to check one number only, this will be the best way.
When you want to check multiple numbers or check multiple conditions, it could be necessary to use `OR` instead.

The above query using `OR` would be this one:

```
SELECT order_id, cust_name, tel1, tel2, tel3 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE tel1 = 65432100 OR tel2 = 65432100 OR tel3 = 65432100
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can try this:

```js
select *
from `your_table_name`
where TEL1 = '65432110' OR TEL2='65432110' OR TEL3='65432110';
```